# 'Cannot use import statement outside of a module' error in @ionic/react when using Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, next.js13

Whenever im trying to build or just run the dev server using nextjs, im getting the following error:

```
unhandledRejection C:\proj\node_modules\@ionic\react\dist\index.js:1
import React, { useContext, useRef, useEffect, createElement, useState, useMemo, Fragment, useCallback } from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1175:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)   
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at 244 (C:\proj\.next\server\pages\_app.js:50:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\proj\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42) {
  type: 'SyntaxError'
}
```

I'm using next-transpile modules:

```js
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")([
  "@ionic/react",
  "@ionic/core",
  "@stencil/core",
  "ionicons",
]);

module.exports = withTM({
  basePath: "'./src",
  swcMinify: true,
});
```

My app.tsx:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Script from "next/script";
  
/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import "@ionic/react/css/core.css";
import "../css/global.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import "@ionic/react/css/normalize.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/structure.css"; // Remove if nothing is visible
import "@ionic/react/css/typography.css";

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import "@ionic/react/css/padding.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/display.css";
import { setupIonicReact } from "@ionic/react";

setupIonicReact();

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover"
        />
      </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <Script
          type="module"
          src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.2.3/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"
        ></Script>
        <Script
          noModule
          src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.2.3/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"
        ></Script>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

My tsconfig module is set to "esnext" and type is module in package.json.
Im using nextjs version "13.4.2" and @ionic/react version "7.0.0".
Any help is highly appreciated.

I as using vite earlier and it was working, but after switched to nextjs, it stopped working.

Ive tried figeting with the configs, nothing worked.

Comment: Any particular reason you're even messing with CJS, `require` and `exports`?

Comment: @morganney I'm not messing with anything, the app isn't building or even running the dev server because of this error.

Comment: If you wrote this code `const withTM = require` then you're "messing" with CJS. I'm wondering why write your source code with ESM but then tell your build tools to target CJS?

Comment: @morganney only the next config is a .cjs file, nothing else is cjs. Also the issue is with @ionic/react package. Still havent found a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that just reinstalling worked for me